# Recursive Program for Sum of an Array in Python

Tags: python, recursion, parentheses

I've written the following program in Python, it is supposed to use only recursion to output whether or not the number of parentheses is even. For example:

```
nestParen("(())") --> true

nestParen("(((x))") --> false
```

Below is the code from my program. For some reason, it always returns true. Why is this and how can it be fixed? Thank you!

```
def nestParen(string1, max = 0, min = 0): 

    if max == 0:
        max = len(string1) - 1
    checker = False
    if max > min:
        if string1[max] == ")" and string1[min] == "(":
            checker = True
            min = min + 1
            max = max - 1
            if max > min:
                nestParen(string1, max, min)
                print checker
    return checker
nestParen("(((x))")
```

Comment: Please spend some more time formatting your code appropriately.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python recursion and return statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/937000/python-recursion-and-return-statements). Also your approach does not work e.g. for this case: `()()`.

Comment: You don't even use the result of `nestParen(string1, max, min)`. Maybe you meant `checker = nestParen(string1, max, min)`?

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what the title is supposed to do with the question.

Answer (score 0):

A list may be best to keep track of the number of parenthesis you have currently seen. Also, it is easier to create a token system for easier identification. Lastly, cast each string as an `iter`, thus, by using `next`, you can more easily determine if you have finished iteration over the string:

```
import re
import collections
test = ["(())", "(((x))"]
def tokenize():
   token = collections.namedtuple('token', ['type', 'value'])
   token_results = [re.findall('\(|\)|\w+', i) for i in test]
   token_types = {'OPAREN':'\(', 'CPAREN':'\)', 'VAR':'\w+'}
   return [iter(token([a for a, b in token_types.items() if re.findall(b, c)][0], c) for c in i) for i in token_results]


def nestParen(s, current = []):
   checking = next(s, None)
   if not checking and current:
       return False
   if not checking and not current:
       return True
   if checking.type == 'OPAREN':
      return nestParen(s, current+[checking.value])
   if checking.type == 'CPAREN':
      if not current:
        return False
      val = current.pop()
      return nestParen(s, current)
   if checking.type not in ['CPAREN', 'OPAREN']:
      return nestParen(s, current)

final_results = map(nestParen, tokenize())
print(final_results)
```

Output:

```
[True, False]
```

While the tokenization system makes the program longer than other, more algorithmic versions, it is helpful to clearly create a method by which each character in the input strings is tagged and accounted for. This shortens `nestParen` in the long run as in your input it appears that other characters can appear besides `(|)`.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. But could you please explain the purpose of the tokenize function? I don't entirely understand what it is supposed to do?

Comment: @EeshaAgarwal The tokenize function makes it easier to identify key characters in the text.